# Required permissions to user CloudFormer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have few aws users, in which I should allow them to user CloudFormer in order to map my infrastructure, so later on it can be used to create the template for cloudformation.
Since I don't want to give them the full address, what are the permissions that I have to set, in order to allow them performing a such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only access control that CloudFormer provides is IP address based restrictions. The cloudformer template will prompt you for the allowed addresses when you run the cloudformation template for it.

If you want to further restrict access, one option would be to spin up a Windows EC2 instance with an EIP, create accounts on that instance for the users you want to authorize to use CloudFormer, then build your CloudFormer stack and restrict it to the IP address of the Windows instance (CIDR format, so the EIP address with a /32 at the end.

Your authorized users can log in to the windows box, hit the browser and access cloudformer.